# OpenCv ANN training same data different outputs

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am using ANN from openCV for image classification. I have feature vector for each image and I train those vectors with 
`CvANN_MLP.train()` method.

My question is WHY, I always get different Network settings on the same data.
For example if I do the Training procedure and Predict procedure (same data, same features, same network settings) in cycle three times. I will get three different network configurations and three different outputs (Like totally different of precision rate for example 60%, 70%, 90%).

I would assume that the resulted network should be every time same on the same data with the same settings, but it is not :/. Any Ideas why?
I found online that there is a chance that "bias" values is affecting, but I couldn't find how to change the `bias` value.

If you have any ideas or relevant links, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from algorithm and initialization, from what i know with typical Feed Forward NN and BackPropagation with gradient descend algorithm:

Typical training algo for such NN's initializes weights of NN randomly (starting point), NN itself has many local optimas, thus you can find many different suboptimal solutions, and if you start from different initialization you probably will find another solution. That's why final solution much depends from starting point.

So if you will keep all parameters and initialization same, you will find same solutions.

I don't know exactly OpenCV API for NN's, and don't know how to force it to initialize NN not randomly, but maybe you can find some parameter to feed pseudo random number generator seed into it.

You can google any papers about initialization of NN, because choosing starting point for NN is a well known problem, and random initialization is not good in most cases, but it is simple.
You can just read abstracts from [here](https://www.elen.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es2001-6.pdf), [here](http://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/~gudwin/ftp/publications/sbrn98.pdf) or [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/momentum.pdf)